# Backbone.js - XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: backbone.js, xmlhttprequest

I'm using backbone.js as my javascript framework for my project. I got this error when retrieve data through API.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://izify.com/api/izify-api/user/get_all_categories.php?merchantId=74718912a2c0d82feb2c14604efecb6d. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://staging.revivalx.com' is therefore not allowed access. staging.revivalx.com/:1
error SidebarView.js:23

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://izify.com/api/izify-api/user/get_all_products.php?merchantId=74718912a2c0d82feb2c14604efecb6d. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://staging.revivalx.com' is therefore not allowed access. staging.revivalx.com/:1
error HomeView.js:23
```

SidebarView.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','models/global/GlobalModel','collections/category/CategoryCollection', 'text!templates/sidebar/sidebarTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone,GlobalModel,CategoryCollection, sidebarTemplate) {
    var SidebarView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#sidebar"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
        },
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            var global = new GlobalModel();
            this.collection = new CategoryCollection();
            var formValues = {
                merchantId: global.merchantId
            };
            this.collection.fetch({
                data: formValues,
                success: function(collection, response) {
                    var template = _.template(sidebarTemplate,{
                        categories: that.collection.models
                    });
                    $("#sidebar").append(template);
                },
                error: function(collection, response) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });            
        }
    });
    return SidebarView;
});
```

HomeView.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone','models/global/GlobalModel','collections/product/ProductCollection','views/sidebar/SidebarView','text!templates/home/homeTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone,GlobalModel,ProductCollection,SidebarView, homeTemplate) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#page"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
        },
        render: function() {
            var that = this;
            var global = new GlobalModel();
            this.collection = new ProductCollection();
            var formValues = {
                merchantId: global.merchantId
            };
            this.collection.fetch({
                 data: formValues,
                success: function(collection, response) {
                    var template = _.template(homeTemplate, {
                        products: that.collection.models
                    });
                    that.$el.html(template);
                },
                error: function(collection, response) {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });

            var sidebarView = new SidebarView();
            sidebarView.render();
        },
    });
    return HomeView;
});
```

My API header

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET');
```

I already upload my source code in github : https://github.com/datomnurdin/izify-template

Demo: http://staging.revivalx.com/izify-template/

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Did you understood my post?

Comment: nope because no any sample of source code according to my problem.

Comment: API that you use is on PHP...

So you don't ablre to resolve this problem on client side with jsvascript only. You need to change server side code. But you did not provided any samples of server side code. Do you get?

Comment: now, can you see my API header?

Comment: yes, i see header, but are you sure that API support this CORS?

Comment: How I can trace it is support or not?

Comment: To test API CORS support you can use http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43893/discussion-between-dato-mohammad-nurdin-and-sergeykutsko)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) problem, you could not sove this with client side only.

To test API CORS support you can use [test CORS](http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client)

So you can solve this by:

1. Implement CORS support on API server side.
2. Proxy requests from your app server side to API.
3. Use another techics  to cross-origin policy like(JSONP, etc..)